# Effective divisors and cones

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $X$ be a normal projective variety, and let $\text{Div}(X)$ be the group of Cartier divisors on $X$. I know that $\text{Div}(X)$ is a free abelian group, hence I can consider the associated real vector space $\text{Div}(X)_{\mathbb{R}}$ - which will be of infinite dimension in general -. Moreover, I can consider the set $E(X)$ of effective real Cartier divisors.

There is a natural map $\pi: \text{Div}(X)_{\mathbb{R}}\to \text{N}^1(X)_{\mathbb{R}}$, sending every divisor to its numerical class. Inside $\text{N}^1(X)_{\mathbb{R}}$, which is now a finite dimensional vector space, I can consider the cone of effective divisors $\text{Eff}(X)$, which in general is not closed.

Consider the preimage $\pi^{-1}(\text{Eff}(X))$: is it still a cone? Does it coincide to $E(X)$?

I've thought about it for a while, these are my ideas:

- obviously $E(X)$ is not a vector space, since it is not closed by -negative- scalar multiplication
- I strongly believe $E(X)$ is a cone, since it is closed by addition and -positive- scalar multiplication
- I still don't know though if $E(X)=\pi^{-1}(\text{Eff}(X))$: I think so, but it confuses me if there may exist a non-effective divisor $D$ whose numerical class belong to the effective cone.

Comment: $\operatorname{Div}(X)$ need not be free. You can still consider $\operatorname{Div}(X)_\mathbb{R}$, but all torsion is lost passing to the tensor product.

Comment: Dear @Smn, thanks for the reply! I thought $\text{Div}(X)$ was free: it is a subgroup of a free abelian group (the group of Weil divisors), hence it is still free abelian

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood your question, to clarify: If you mean the free abelian group generated by Cartier divisors, then yes it is free abelian by definition. If you mean the group modulo linear equivalence, then the answer is no.

Comment: I mean the first one, the free abelian group generated by Cartier divisors! Otherwise I would have talked about the Picard group, which yes as you observed may have torsion ;)

Comment: In that case the sets you describe are not equal. Take any distinct subschemes $D_1,D_2$ that are linearly equivalent. Then $D_1-D_2$ is linearly (hence numerically) equivalent to 0, but not contained in your set $E(X)$.

Comment: I see, $D_1-D_2$ belong to the numerical class of an effective divisor, but its preimage is not. This is indeed the phenomenon I was afraid of: thanks!